# Say command that disables @everyone for non-administrators

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

EDIT: I have fixed the code by just using another method, thanks for the other helpful answers though!

I'm making a say command, it just takes the user's message and repeats it via the bot. But it can be abused to ping everyone etc. So I want to make it so when the User isn't an admin it checks the message for @everyone or @here. Then it says that you can't ping everyone and reacts to the output 'You cant ping everyone' message with a custom command.
It's also in a cog btw. The command, when used, doesn't throw any console errors, instead not doing anything.
EDIT: I have fixed the code by just using another method, thanks for the other helpful answers though!

```
    @commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if not ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            if "@everyone" in message or "@here" in message:
                antiping = "You can't mention everyone through me!"
                await ctx.send(antiping)
                await antiping.add_reaction(emoji=':Canteveryone:890319257534103603')
                return
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: I think the problem of your command might be that if the author is not an admin, and the message does not contain `@everyone`, it will not do anything. You need to write an `else`-statement for the `if "@everyone" in message..` statement. Also you should remove the `ctx.message.delete()` in the last `else` block, because you already delete the message in your code beforehand.

Comment: Oh also consider using clean_content: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=clean%20content#discord.ext.commands.clean_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`allowed_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AllowedMentions)** for this. Two ways of using this:

1. Pass in `Bot` when initializing:

```
client = bot(.....,
          allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = False)
)
```

2. You can also pass the same object when sending a message:

```
ctx.send(...,
         allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = False)
)
```

I'd recommend you read the docs for more info on how it works.

You can adjust mentions for the following attributes:

- `everyone`
- `replied_user`
- `roles`
- `users`

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this would be when you execute your command, it modifies the role "everyone" so that they cant ping the role

Admins bypass **ALL** restrictions so they would still be able to ping the role besides

Comment: Hi, my server has @ everyone disabled for normal members, but they can still say @ everyone through the bot even if they cant mention @ everyone, the bot still mentions everyone then. Sorry if thats not what you meant!